# scikit-learn CountVectorizer vocabulary with regex

Tags: scikit-learn, text-analysis, countvectorizer

Having a corpus like this:

```
'This is the first document.',
'This document is the second document.',
'And this is the third one.',
'Is this the first document?'
```

I'm using this vocabulary ["this", "document", "this document"].
After the vectorizer fit, I'm getting these result:

```
[[1 1 0]
[1 2 1]
[1 0 0]
[1 1 0]]
```

which is correct. 
Is there a way I can use regex (or something else) in order to take "this document" feature in the first row of my corpus?
More specifically this [1  1  1] than [1  1  0]?

My row is this: ["This is the first document"]. 
Can I somehow "remove" the words "is the first" (or whatever words) to get "this document" feature? Maybe with token_pattern?

Comment: A countVectorizer should print absolute counts of the features. Why are your values in floats? How do you know these are correct? Show the code and explain more.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I just edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just figure it out. What I actually wanted to do is to create features based on all word combination on my corpora (unigrams and bigrams).
For example, my row: This is the first document.
Extracted features:

```
this, 
is, 
the, 
first, 
document, 
this is, 
this the, 
this document, 
is the, 
is first, 
is document, 
the first, 
the document, 
first document
```

I made this by writing my own tokenizer and using it on the tokenizer parameter of my CountVectorizer().